# Firestore logging and custom logs - custom react native application logs in firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react-native to write my mobile app. 
Now, during the development, I am writing some console.log statements to see the errors or track what is going on in my app. Strictly for debugging purposes. 
But in the end, I am considering to store the logs related to exceptions happening in my application. I am considering to create one or more collections and storing warnings/errors in those collections so that later I can query them and take necessary administrative measures if necessary.

What I want to know is if there is a logging mechanism provided by firestore out of the box. 
I found this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs so logging is very easy with cloud functions. But I want to log for my application problems and the only way I can think of is to create one or more collections for this purpose and write error/warning documents into those collections. Any suggestions?

Comment: Firebase doesn't offering anything specifically. You should look into StackDriver, which is part of Google Cloud.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the comment. Do you think I can integrate StackDriver as described here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/stackdriver-errors-js#setup-for-javascript and use it in my react-native project to log client-side errors? Another thing... It feels like stack driver is catching unhandled errors. I can't have unhandled errors in my app crashing on the users. My aim is to caths the errors inside try-catch blocks and .catch handlers, handle the problem gracefully then log the error data. Do you think stack driver is good for that also? Can you lead me to an example?